# Find certificate by thumbprint

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate

System can't find certificate by string thumbprint

```
       var thumbprint = "‎2E7F6E8A0124E6745C3999EE15770C0A4931F342";
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        var c = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false).OfType<X509Certificate>().FirstOrDefault();
```

this core returns null. But I try this too

```
foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates)
        {

           var c= store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, mCert.Thumbprint, false).Count;
        }
```

c is always 1 , so some problem is in characters. I copied this thumbprint value.

Comment: Is there a leading space in the thumbprint value? For some reason in some cases it displays one - in my experience - if you use the certificate snap-in, but that is NOT part of the thumbprint.

Comment: this is value var thumbprint="‎2E7F6E8A0124E6745C3999EE15770C0A4931F342"

Comment: See this question , maybe it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448147/problems-with-x509store-certificates-find-findbythumbprint

Comment: Below link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115511/how-to-find-certificate-by-its-thumbprint-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
    public async Task<X509Certificate2> GetCertificate(string certificateThumbprint)
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var cert = store.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Thumbprint == certificateThumbprint);
        store.Close();
        return cert;
    }
```

Comment: Why method `GetCertificate` is async?

Comment: This is definitely the better way to go instead of .Find().