# C# making https request with httpclient

Tags: c#, ssl, https, dotnet-httpclient

**UPD: This code work in windows server 2012, but dont work in windows 7,8,10. And i haven't any idea why**

I am trying to make post request to some service that allows only https connection. But i get error

`The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel`

My code

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    var response = await client.PostAsync(ApiAddress, content);
    var xml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var transaction = DeserializeXml<StationsResponseTransaction>(xml);
    return transaction;
}
```

This service gave certificate (.crt) and private key (.pem) files. Maybe i need to use these files? But how?

**UPDATE:** 
I tried create pfx certificate and add it in WebRequestHandler

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("Certificate.pfx", "password");
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
```

and use handler in client `new HttpClient(handler)`

But i got same error

**UPDATE**: Just tested this request in postman - working fine, when server's certificate accepted from google crhome. But how to accept certificate from C# httpclient?

`ServicePointManager`'s `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` event not called

Comment: Is the certificate signed with a trusted root certificate (even your own self-generated one)?

Comment: Maybe the server doesn't support the protocols or ciphers you need. You can check with ssllabs: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: @Jasen i dont know, and i dont know how to do this

Comment: You basically use Powershell to 1) create the signing cert 2) install the cert to your trusted certificates 3) create the (second) cert your application uses, **signed by the trusted cert**.

Comment: I used this guy's guide in the past: http://blog.davidchristiansen.com/2016/09/howto-create-self-signed-certificates-with-powershell/

Comment: @ Kaushal yes, i am tried with  WebRequestHandler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback - same situation, callback not even hitting

Comment: @Kaushal can you say more about how to find it? T

Comment: @StasPetrov use X509Store() for more detail 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448147/problems-with-x509store-certificates-find-findbythumbprint       and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make .cer file from your .pfx, and then install it to trusted folder in local.
Then make client .cer from .pfc, and use it in solution (don't install it).